# Get LayoutBuilder height in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm having a Row that contain an Expand(LayoutBuilder(Widget that can change vertical size by the user))) and Column on the right like the code. I want the height of column is equal to the height (vertical length) of the left widget. The column heigh should also able to change according to the height of the left widget.

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: Center(
        child: Row(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, size) {
                return TextField(
                  maxLines: null,
                );
              }),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                InkWell(
                  child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_up),
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
                InkWell(
                  child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
```

To look similar to this. My first solution is somehow get the LayoutBuilder height and use it for the container of the column. Any other better way to make it the same look and behavior as describe is fine.

[image: layout goal]

Comment: You could just put an alignment property on the container holding the column so to make it expand to its fullest extent. Also use the mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max property to let the column expand completely. Utilize the alignment properties within the column to let the children do what they need from there.

Comment: @AdrianMurray I'm not sure I understand your help, feel free to submit a sample code as a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the `Row` inside the `LayoutBuilder`, like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("")),
    body: Container(
      child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, size) {
        return Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: TextField(
                  maxLines: null,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  InkWell(
                    child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_up),
                    onTap: () {},
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                    onTap: () {},
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      }),
    ),
  );
}
```

**Edit:** This would make the height of the `Row` take the height of it's parent.

If you want the height of the `Row` to be the minimum height, in this case you could wrap the `Row` with an `IntrinsicHeight`, take care that the use of `IntrinsicHeight` could be expensive so don't use it every time if you can restructure your widgets to avoid it.

Comment: The problem is I can not wrap the whole thing in another Column or ListView because it try to take maximum heigh which is infinity. I want the LayoutBuilder to use minimum height which is just equal to the size of the TextField.

Comment: I did work; however, I would use a lot of widgets like this (can be more than 25) so this might not the ideal solution.

Comment: I think some use of LimitedBox and FittedBox would be cheaper here.